# Sync Iphone IOS 10.1

Tags: music, iphone

Does anyone know how to sync Iphone 5s IOS 10.1 with elementary?

I can mount the iphone and see my pictures/videos but I would like to be able to sync my music. I tried with Noise and Rhythmbox and had no success.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Its not supported. With a jailbroken iPhone and a 20 dollar tweak it can be done with Rhythmbox. I doubt the tweak works out. 10.1 yet, and I haven't kept up with the current state of jailbreak.

I'd suggest using a different method.  I have a plex account so I use it to sync/stream videos and music. On iOS I really. Luke's cloudbeats for music and audio books.
http://www.cloudbeatsapp.com
https://www.plex.tv/

Plenty of other apps out there. These are just my favorites.

Answer (score 1):

To sync music between a computer and an iPhone, iTunes is required. Unfortunately, Apple has not made iTunes for linux. However, maybe you can try something like this: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=31322

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this isn't what you're asking, but I use a different workflow to achieve the net-effect of having music synced to my phone. Run a Plex or Kodi media server, and then use the Plex phone app or Yatze app to stream and sync media to your phone.

My actual setup is this:

- Synology NAS storing the media
- Nextcloud on a Raspberry Pi, mounting the NAS to see/use files
- Kodi running on a separate machine as the media server to play media on my TV and serve to mobile apps
- Firefox and/or Webpin to play music from Kodi on Elementary via the Kodi web UI

It's a bit more complicated than synching music directly to a phone, but brings other benefits and requires no cables to sync.